# React-native: components won't render past a certain point down the screen on android

Tags: android, react-native

Android won't render any of my components after about 75% of the way down the screen. See image below: iPhone is on the left, rendering everything as it should. Android is on the right, not rendering the text field and 2 buttons at the bottom.

[image]

Here is the component tree:

```js
return (
            <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: colors.JBTan}}>
                <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>
                            Join Private Game:
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{width: '90%'}}>
                        <TextField
                            placeholder='Game Name...'
                            maxLength={12}
                            onChangeText={GameName => this.setState({GameName})}
                        />
                    </View>
                    {message1}
                    <View style={{width: '90%'}}>
                        <TextField
                            placeholder='Password...'
                            maxLength={12}
                            onChangeText={Password => this.setState({Password})}
                        />
                    </View>
                    {message2}
                    <View style={{width: '90%'}}>
                        <TextField
                            placeholder='Player Name...'
                            maxLength={10}
                            onChangeText={Name => this.setState({Name})}
                        />
                    </View>
                    {message3}
                    <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                        <PrimaryButton
                            onPress={() => this.joinPrivateGame()}
                            label="Join Game"
                        >
                        </PrimaryButton>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>
                            Join Public Game:
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View
                        style={{
                            width: '90%',
                            height: '30%',
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            borderColor: colors.JBDarkTeal,
                            backgroundColor: 'white',
                            marginBottom: 5,
                            paddingBottom: 10,
                            marginTop: 10,
                        }}
                    >
                        <ScrollView>
                            <FlatList
                                data={this.state.game_names}
                                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                                extraData={this.state.game_selected}
                            />
                        </ScrollView>
                    </View>
                    // nothing rendering from here down...
                    {message4}
                    <View style={{width: '90%'}}>
                        <TextField
                            placeholder='Player Name...'
                            maxLength={10}
                            onChangeText={NamePublic => this.setState({NamePublic})}
                        />
                    </View>
                    {message5}
                    <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                        <PrimaryButton
                            onPress={() => this.joinPublicGame()}
                            label="Join Game"
                        >
                        </PrimaryButton>
                        <PrimaryButton
                            onPress={() => this.goBack()}
                            label="Go Back"
                        >
                        </PrimaryButton>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
```

In the styles of the view container around the scrollview and flatlist, if I change height to 20%, the android looks like this, so you can see where it is cut off:

[image]

I get the same result with android studio and Genymotion. Any idea why it would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why, but in the View wrapped around the flatlist, it doesn't like me using height: '30%'. changing it to height: (Dimensions.get('window').height) * .2 gives the result I want.

```js
<View
    style={{
        width: '90%',
        height: (Dimensions.get('window').height) * .2,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: colors.JBDarkTeal,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        marginBottom: 5,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        marginTop: 10,
    }}
>
    <ScrollView>
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.game_names}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            extraData={this.state.game_selected}
        />
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```